# Use Jquery Cookie to store and update a counter variable during page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using .NET and C#. I'm calling a Javascript function from the code behind based on a condition.

Problem: I want to call a seperate JS function when a variable reaches above 1. The issue with that is it seems the browser resets the counter variable, or I've done something wrong.

Here is if my first try at doing this

```
var myFunctionCalls = 0; //To track how many times this function gets called
function TTclubConfirmUw1(){
      if(myFunctionCalls < 1){
        //Do something here
        myFunctionCalls++;
      }
      else{
        //Call another method after the variable reaches 1
        // reset myFunctionCalls back to zero  (myFunctionCalls = 0;)

}
```

it seems the increment call works. As I've alerted out to see what happens, but it doesn't stay after the page refreshes ..Which happens in the code behind.

I then tried a JQuery cookie. Encountered some errors just getting it to this point, but it seems I've missed something with it as well. P.S. I've used the js-cookie plug in as well.

I want to have a counter that is incremented each time a certain function is called. Use that counter for conditional logic.

Here is what I have:

```
  var myFuncCalls = 0;


    function ContactUW() {
     var cookies = Cookies.set("count", "myFuncCalls", {expires: 1} );

        if (cookies > 0) {
            alert(Cookies.get('count')+ "GT");
        } else {
            alert(Cookies.get('count') + "LT");
        myFuncCalls++;

        }

    }
```

This was only to test and see if I could get it working. Never does.. brings back "myFuncCallsLT" When what I want is the value and eventually incremmented value myFuncCalls

EDIT -----------------------------------------------
After the help below I thought I would also post the help received.

This does in fact assign the value I was looking for to this cookie. I found another usable solution(I posted below, but I could use this one just the same. with some slight tweaks)

I tested it this was to confirm it works upon the page refresh. The only oddity is the ++ increment operator wouldn't work correctly. So, I had add to FunctionCalls the way you see.

```
   var FunctionCalls = 0;
    window.onload = function TestTwo() {
        if (Cookies.get("count") > 0) {
            alert(Cookies.get('count') + "LT");
        } else {
            alert(Cookies.get('count') + "GT");
            FunctionCalls = FunctionCalls + 1;
                   Cookies.set("count", FunctionCalls);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the cookie value as a string of "myFuncCalls" rather than actually setting the value, you need to change it to the following (i.e. remove the double quotes around myFuncCalls):

```
var myFuncCalls = 0;


    function ContactUW() {
     var cookies = Cookies.set("count", myFuncCalls, {expires: 1} );

        if (cookies > 0) {
            alert(Cookies.get('count')+ "GT");
        } else {
            alert(Cookies.get('count') + "LT");
        myFuncCalls++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: trfletch, thanks. You're absolutely right. I'll edit the question to reflect How I confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't answer the question exactly. Specifically using the JQuery cookie method. However, I did find and am able accomplish what I wanted doing something a bit different.

Recap: I needed a way to conditionally determine what JS function to call in the code behind. I tried counters, bools. Even fooled around with a session variable. Nothing worked. It either assumed it was the assigned value of 0 or if incremented it, it never would stay that newly incremented value when the page refreshed.

So, I used a hiddenField .NET variable.

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hf2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I call this method in the code behind.

```
  public void TTclubMethod()
    {
        //send JS message to user. Contact underwriter first.
        bool contactUW = false;


        // determine what value #hf2 holds to determine what JS func to call
        if (hf2.Value == String.Empty)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "ContactUW();", true);
            string var = hf2.Value.ToString(); //Testing 
            MessageBox.Show(var); //Testing
        }
        else
        {
            //Create blank template message and update DB. 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "TTclubConfirmUw();", true);


        }
    }
```

The initial value is always blank.. calls the first JS function

```
 function ContactUW() {
     var close = bootbox.alert({
                message: '<p class="text-center"><b>This is a TTCLUB policy. Please contact the underwriter about the renewal process. </b></p>',
                size: "large",
                closeButton: true
        });

        var hf2 = document.getElementById("hf2");
        hf2.value = 1;
    }
```

And I set the hidden field value to 1. Next time I call that C# method, it logically moves to the next JS function to call.

```
"TTclubConfirmUw();"
```

Depending what the user chooses determine whether I keep the hidden field value at 1 or reset it back to empty again.

I'm sure there were more elegant ways of doing this, but this solved the problem and it consistently works. Maybe this will help someone else.